# What the difference between insert, update and save?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

What the difference between theese methods
`.insert_many()`, `.save()`, `.update()`, `.update_many()` ?

---

I want to push the docs to database and if the same doc was exist it will be updated or if no exsist it will be created

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried the .update(upsert=True), but python show me that this method is deprecated and the question which method is better for my task

Comment: post the code you have tried

Comment: I don't use python but a quick Google suggests you have a look at replace https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html

Comment: @deadshot i only use "collection.update(file, upsert=true)" code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From docs](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update)

> update(spec, document, upsert=False, manipulate=False, multi=False, check_keys=True, **kwargs)
> Update a document(s) in this collection.
>
> DEPRECATED - Use replace_one(), update_one(), or update_many() instead.

Example query using `update_one()`

```
collection.update_one({'key': 'value'}, {'$set': {'new_key': 'new_value'}}, upsert=True)
```

Using `replace_one()`

```
collection.update_one({'key': 'value'}, {'new_key': 'new_value'}, upsert=True)
```